# Kotlin constructor parameter without getter

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View, val ui: ViewUI)
```

I don't want that the field ui have a getter, but kotlin is generating it by default since it is a val defined in the constructor.

In the [properties and fields document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) I found that I can generate a private getter with the following code

```
var setterVisibility: String = "abc"
    private set
```

But I can't find a way to do this in the constructor definition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make the entire property private in the constructor, that way it will only be accessible inside the class:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View, private val ui: ViewUI)
```